# Interpretation of "(see) references therein"

Tags: traduction, anglais, citations, académique

> Doe et al. collected in their recent review a large number of earlier
>   work (see Doe, 2012 and references therein).

J'ai vu plusieurs façons de rendre *references therein*. Ex.

> Doe et al. rassembla dans leur récente revue un grand nombre de travaux antérieurs (voir Doe, 2012 et **références qui y figurent/qui s'y trouvent/y continues/données dedans**).

Laquelle est la plus correcte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doe *et al.*<sup>1</sup> ont<sup>2</sup> répertorié dans leur étude<sup>3</sup> récente de nombreux travaux antérieurs (voir Doe, 2012 et références incluses).

Pour ce qui est de tes propositions, *références...* :

- *qui y figurent* : un peu lourd et pas très adapté;
- *qui s'y trouvent* : un peu lourd mais correct;
- *y continues* : agrammatical et erreur de mot, j'imagine que tu voulais dire *contenues*;
- *données dedans* : le sens y est, mais pas le registre.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Latin en italiques.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Sujets coordonnés avec *et* : pluriel.</sub>
<sup>3</sup> <sub>Une revue est surtout un magazine.</sub>

Comment: Merci ! Les variantes dans la question sont-elles pas courantes, voire erronées ?

Comment: Pourquoi aussi étude et pas revue (pour review) ?

Comment: Zut, j'ai up-voté ta réponse plutôt que la mienne ! C'est ça mon problème, je suis trop honnête !  (et je ne peux pas up-voter ma réponse)

Comment: @SteffX J'ai up-voté toutes les deux réponses:-)!

Comment: Parfait, merci encore pour l'édit.

Comment: Merci @dimitris

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, *"et références"* est suffisant en tant que raccourci pour *"et références qui y figurent"*, surtout que l'on utilise ce genre de notation dans un certain contexte.

"qui s'y trouvent" est trop familier pour moi et les autres propositions ("y continues/données dedans") incompréhensibles.

Answer (score 1):

Les quatre possibilités proposées sont pour le moins gauches. « Et (les) références citées dans ce dernier » n'est pas trop long et sans risque de causer la moindre équivoque.